# Problema al obtener imagen de URL

Tags: php

estoy tratando de obtener la iamgen de una URL con https:// y se supone que lo hace bien, pero al generar el pdf, me devuelve este error:

```
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  exif_imagetype(https://cdn2.depau.es/articulos/448/448/fixed/art_fell-destructora%20w-61cb_1.jpg
): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
 in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\control\controladores\generarOfertaPDFemseel.php</b> on line <b>155</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  exif_imagetype(): Filename cannot be empty in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\control\controladores\generarOfertaPDFemseel.php</b> on line <b>181</b><br />
<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught Exception: FPDF error: Unexpected end of stream in C:\xampp\htdocs\control\controladores\fpdf\fpdf.php:271
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\control\controladores\fpdf\fpdf.php(1403): FPDF-&gt;Error('Unexpected end ...')
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\control\controladores\fpdf\fpdf.php(1267): FPDF-&gt;_readstream(Resource id #14, 8)
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\control\controladores\fpdf\fpdf.php(1259): FPDF-&gt;_parsepngstream(Resource id #14, 'imagen.png')
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\control\controladores\fpdf\fpdf.php(885): FPDF-&gt;_parsepng('imagen.png')
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\control\controladores\generarOfertaPDFemseel.php(227): FPDF-&gt;Image('imagen.png', 130, 15, 40, 38)
#5 {main}
  thrown in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\control\controladores\fpdf\fpdf.php</b> on line <b>271</b><br />
```

mi código actual es el siguiente, quisiera comprobar que tipo de archivo es el que recojo, pero me está dando problemas ahí.

```
if(isset($_POST["imagenProductoBD"])){
    $imagen_url = $_POST["imagenProductoBD"];


    if(exif_imagetype($imagen_url) == IMAGETYPE_JPEG){
        $imagen = 'imagen.png';
    }else{
        $imagen = 'imagen.jpg';
    }


    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $imagen_url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0); // <-- don't forget this
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0); // <-- and this
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $fp = fopen($imagen, 'wb');
    fwrite($fp, $result);
    fclose($fp);
}
```

**SALIDA**

```
resource(8) of type (stream)
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  exif_imagetype(): Filename cannot be empty in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\control\controladores\generarOfertaPDFemseel.php</b> on line <b>185</b><br />
<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught Exception: FPDF error: Unexpected end of stream in C:\xampp\htdocs\control\controladores\fpdf\fpdf.php:271
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\control\controladores\fpdf\fpdf.php(1403): FPDF-&gt;Error('Unexpected end ...')
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\control\controladores\fpdf\fpdf.php(1267): FPDF-&gt;_readstream(Resource id #14, 8)
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\control\controladores\fpdf\fpdf.php(1259): FPDF-&gt;_parsepngstream(Resource id #14, 'imagen.png')
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\control\controladores\fpdf\fpdf.php(885): FPDF-&gt;_parsepng('imagen.png')
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\control\controladores\generarOfertaPDFemseel.php(231): FPDF-&gt;Image('imagen.png', 130, 15, 40, 38)
#5 {main}
  thrown in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\control\controladores\fpdf\fpdf.php</b> on line <b>271</b><br />
```

**CREACIÓN PDF**

```
// CREAMOS el PDF
$pdf = new PDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
// PRIMER DIGITO ES LA POSICIÓN A LA IZQUIERDA, SEGUNDO ALTURA, TERCERO ANCHURA IMAGEN, CUARTO ALTURA IMAGEN
//$pdf->Image('../vistas/img/logoIntegra.png',10 ,22, 80, 38, 'png');
$pdf->Nombre();
$pdf->escribeNombre();
$pdf->Apellidos();
$pdf->escribeApellidos();
$pdf->Telefono();
$pdf->escribeTelefono();
$pdf->Dni();
$pdf->escribeDni();
$pdf->Fecha();
$pdf->escribeFecha();
$pdf->Articulo();
$pdf->escribeArticulo();
$pdf->Precio();
$pdf->escribePrecio();
$pdf->Image($imagen, 130, 15, 40, 38); // esta es la línea de la iamgen del articulo
$pdf->Detalles();
$pdf->escribeDetalles();
```

Comment: Parece que la llamada para obtener `https://cdn2.depau.es/articulos/448/448/fixed/art_fell-destructora%20w-61cb_1.jpg` obtiene un *HTTP status* 404... es decir, que la URL está mal y no existe ese fichero JPG. Lo curioso es que sí que puedo verlo si uso esa URL

Comment: Si, pero me pasa siempre... Como podría obtener de la URL el tipo de archivo que es?? Png o jpg??

Comment: Hice [una prueba](https://paiza.io/projects/Xum-dHLWvmh0ZLUwQDVMaQ) y devuelve `2`. Quizás tengas mal configurado [`allow_url_fopen `](https://www.php.net/manual/es/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen)

Comment: A que te refieres con 2??? En teoría lo está haciendo bien, no??? El allow_url_fopen lo configuré, si este fragmento de código ha estado funcionando... Pero no se porque ahora falla. Además quiero hacer que detecte bien la extensión del archivo

Comment: Exacto, el código funciona correctamente. A lo mejor es un problema de configuración de `PHP` o del Firewall del ordenador

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115097/discussion-on-question-by-scorpions-problema-al-obtener-imagen-de-url).

Comment: No reconozco llamadas como esta: `$pdf->Articulo(); $pdf->escribeArticulo();` ... etc ... ¿Todo eso son métodos de tu clase PDF?

Comment: @A.Cedano si efectivamente. he hecho lo que me has dicho de generar el PDF con la imagen sola y sigue igual

Comment: He comprobado tambien el allow_url_fopen y está en "on"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya lo he solucionado. Primeramente compruebo en el javascript lo que estoy recibiendo.

```
// comprobamos la imagen que estamos seleccionando
// si la introducimos a mano o viene de la BD
var imagenProducto = "";

if($("#imagenProductoBD").attr("src") == ""){
    imagenProducto = $("#resultadoImagen").attr("src");
}else{
    imagenProducto = $("#imagenProductoBD").attr("src");
}
```

una vez comprobado, esta variable la enviamos por AJAX. La recibimos por POST en phpy comprobamos si está seteada. También comprobamos la extensión del archivo y con todo eso descargamos la imagen. Quitamos los posibles espacios en blanco que pudiera traer también.

```
//comprobamos que la imagen viaja ya sea la de la BD o la que le establezcamos
$imagen = "";


if(isset($_POST["imagenProducto"])){
    $imagen_url = trim($_POST["imagenProducto"]);

    $ext = pathinfo(parse_url($imagen_url, PHP_URL_PATH), PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    if($ext == "png"){
        $imagen = "imagen.png";
    }else{
        $imagen = "imagen.jpg";
    }

    file_put_contents($imagen, file_get_contents($imagen_url));
}
```

Todo esto me permite, descargar una imagen desde una URL externa a mi, comprobar si la imagen del producto está vacía en la BD y si está vacía damos la posibilidad de agregarla para posteriormente crear un PDF bien con la imagen de la BD o la que establecemos manualmente